# Not able to migrate sonarqube 6.4 to 6.6

Tags: sonarqube

When I tried to upgrade sonarqube 6.4 to 6.6 the server failed to start with following error in the web.log file.

```
2017.12.21 18:12:29 INFO  web[][o.s.s.n.NotificationDaemon] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2017.12.21 18:12:29 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [rules/activeRule] ...
2017.12.21 18:12:31 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of type [rules/activeRule] done | time=1480ms
2017.12.21 18:12:31 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Indexing of types [rules/ruleExtension],[rules/rule] ...
2017.12.21 18:12:33 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unrecoverable indexation failures
    at org.sonar.server.es.IndexingListener$1.onFinish(IndexingListener.java:39)
    at org.sonar.server.es.BulkIndexer.stop(BulkIndexer.java:117)
    at org.sonar.server.rule.index.RuleIndexer.indexOnStartup(RuleIndexer.java:90)
    at org.sonar.server.es.IndexerStartupTask.indexUninitializedTypes(IndexerStartupTask.java:68)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at org.sonar.server.es.IndexerStartupTask.execute(IndexerStartupTask.java:55)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:91)
    at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:45)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:87)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:196)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.access$400(Platform.java:46)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.lambda$doRun$1(Platform.java:121)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.runIfNotAborted(Platform.java:371)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.doRun(Platform.java:121)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.run(Platform.java:355)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2017.12.21 18:12:33 INFO  web[][o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process
2017.12.21 18:12:33 INFO  web[][o.s.s.n.NotificationDaemon] Notification service stopped
2017.12.21 18:12:33 INFO  web[][o.s.s.n.NotificationDaemon] Notification service stopped
```

I was using postgreSQL for DB. The error happened after upgrade of sonarqube from the `setup` URL.

Comment: Why not upgrading to 6.7 LTS? Have a look in the logging made during execution of the upgrade. Do you see any issues?

Comment: Have you try a second time ? If yes, then could you try to delete the data/es folder ?